# How long does it take to build MacVim from source?

Tags: xcode4, build, macvim, xcodebuild, homebrew

I am trying to install MacVim in my Macbook Pro from Homebrew. However it "got stuck" at

```
 xcodebuild -project MacVim/Macvim.xcodeproj ARCHS="x86_64" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCHS="NO"
```

for nearly 6 hours. Last time I remember building from source that took me so long was the Open Office.

By the way. I am running Lion. I know there is no stable version of MacVim for Lion yet but I guess this shouldn't be a problem building it. I have Xcode 4 installed with Command Line Tools.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: After 12 hours I gave up. I hit ctrl + c and went to bed.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. What happened is that I installed the command line tools for xcode but its path was not properly configured. For example, to compile MacVim it required xcodebuild to run. The only reference for xcodebuild I found in my system was in /usr/bin so I set the path to that location. Even though xcodebuild was being found by make, it would get stuck forever and not returning any erros (weird). I tried to build other application purely based on gcc and it got stuck with no errors too. Finaly I found the correct path for command-line tools for Xcode 4.3. The code to set it up is:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

source: http://jeffreyearly.com/2012/02/28/broken-command-line-tools-clt-in-xcode-4-3/